# Fastest way to create a Converter in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight

When working with Binding converters are pretty common.. I always find myself

- Right-click the correct Folder
- Click Add
- Click New Item
- (Sometimes) Choose Code to the left
- Choose Class and "Add" (and sometimes when I'm in a hurry a create an AboutBox instead :-( )
- Copy an old IValueConverter or IMultiValueConverter
- Change the namespace and the class name
- Remove the old code

and then I can finally start to implement my new converter.

After this I also have to add this namespace to the xaml file and add it to resources before I can reference it. I've been doing this a million times and this is probablly the slowest way to do it so my question is..

What is the fastest way to create a Converter in Visual Studio?

Comment: It takes all of 45 seconds tops...are you creating that many converters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the best resource for you is the Visual Studio templates. You can create your own and so you could right-click/create new item/Converter that would stub in everything that you're doing manually.

If you do create something like that, it would probably be a great little project to share with the community via codeplex or something like that.

[Creating Item Templates in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I'll second this.  I do this for behaviors, converters, and a few other custom classes on my current project.  The time savings isn't as significant as not breaking the flow of my work.  Helps keep my head in the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm gonna try Visual Studio templates! Also I second Raumornie's comment "Helps keep my head in the project".

Answer (score 11):

You can certainly save time on this part:

> - Copy an old IValueConverter or IMultiValueConverter
> - Change the namespace and the class name
> - Remove the old code

Do it this way instead:

- Create a new class (`FooConverter` for instance)
- Make it implement `IValueConverter` by just adding `: IValueConverter`
- With the caret still on `IValueConverter`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to open the smart tag menu
- Select "Implement interface IValueConverter" (should be the first option) from the smart tag menu

Visual Studio will automatically create the necessary method stubs, you just need to write the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is actually my second approach if I don't have any other converter available at the moment. I've always found the copy/paste way to be faster because studio doesn't autocomplete IValueConverter unless the namespace is included. But I guess you are right, this way is probably faster :-) Did you actually get a vote down for this answer? I'll upvote you :)

Answer (score 3):

I like this question and value converters, so i have a little contribution that might not help you, Meleak, but hopefull those who don't have such strict style guidelines and thus can place multiple converters in one file: A snippet that creates the code for a value converter stub.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Value Converter Stub</Title>
            <Shortcut>vc</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for a value converter stub</Description>
            <Author>H.B.</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>from</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The source type.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>object</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>to</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The target type.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>object</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>convertername</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Name of the converter.</ToolTip>
                    <Default>My</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[[ValueConversion(typeof($from$), typeof($to$))]
public class $convertername$Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        $from$ input = ($from$)value;
        $to$ output;

        throw new NotImplementedException();

        return output;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        $to$ input = ($to$)value;
        $from$ output;

        throw new NotImplementedException();

        return output;
    }
}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save this as `vc.snippet` (or something else with the extension `snippet`) in the snippet folder of Visual Studio (for VS2010 on x64 that would be: `"%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#"`). You can also import the snippet via `Tools -> Code Snippet Manager...`.

To use it just type `vc` and hit tab twice, then tab through the two class fields to fill them out.

You might need to add two references for the `ValueConversion`-attribute and `IValueConverter`.

The above snippet is quite verbose so here would be a lighter version (keyword is `vcl`) which omitts the attribute and method frames and has just one editable field which directly sets the complete class name:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Value Converter Stub (Light)</Title>
            <Shortcut>vcl</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for a light value converter stub</Description>
            <Author>H.B.</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>convertername</ID>
                <ToolTip>Name of the converter.</ToolTip>
                <Default>My</Default>
            </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[public class $convertername$Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        $end$
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Very Cool :) I'm definitely gonna try this one!

Answer (score 0):

Keep all of your converter classes in a single file (ie: Converters.cs), then when you need to add one you can do the same copy/paste that you're already doing but you won't have to add a new item, re-namespace, add a new namespace, etc.

At least, that's what I do...

Comment: By the way, are you related to [that guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_O'Driscoll) ? ;)

Comment: I disagree - Copy/paste is very often not the right solution for most people. Those of us who are not careless are usually able to copy/paste without making mistakes.

Comment: The styleguides where I work are very strict about 1 class/file so this isn't an option. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a Value Converter item template to the Visual Studio 2010:
From the Project Context Menu, Add...New Item...Online Templates folder...Silverlight folder...Value Converter.